# Python/Mysql: Refuses to escape string!

Tags: python, mysql, escaping

I have a pretty long query i need to execute, and i'm using prepared statements to insert the values to the query. As far as i know, it's suppose to work, but it's not working!

Here's the code:

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    rows = cursor.execute(r"""SELECT... %s.. %s.. %s...""",(val1,val2,val3,))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    rows = text_position(rows)
```

If i insert a simple-quote it breaks, and same thing if i insert any non-english characters. It works with double-quotes as i wrapped the statement in them. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the error? Posting the actual SQL statement would help too

Comment: It's the ususal `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1' at line 1`. When i insert a non-english character i get this `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`. Sorry, i can't post the query but i can tell you it's a fulltext search. I hope that helps..

Comment: I just solved it! It was just a bad mistake by me, i had used the same variable in another query and that's the query that triggered the error, not this one. Thanks though!

Comment: You really should be using parameterized queries. Your code is open to SQL injection via `val1, val2, val3`.

Comment: What? No, it's secure against SQL injection, i've checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general technique for debugging SQL (especially when generated from another language, like Python):

Stop the mysql server (assuming you run mysqld without logging):

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mysql stop
```

Run `mysqld` with logging turned on:

```
sudo mysqld --log=/tmp/myquery.log
```

Run your script.

Look in /tmp/myquery.log for the SQL command that MySQLdb sent to mysqld.

This might give you enough of a clue to solve the problem, otherwise, please post the complete SQL command in Python

```
cursor.execute(r"""SELECT... %s.. %s.. %s...""",(val1,val2,val3,))
```

and the corresponding SQL as seen by mysqld in /tmp/myquery.log.

Once you are done debugging, you can shutdown the logging mysqld and restart it with:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mysql restart
```